# Unix shell file copy flattening folder structure

Tags: unix, shell

On the UNIX bash shell (specifically Mac OS X Leopard) what would be the simplest way to copy every file having a specific extension from a folder hierarchy (including subdirectories) to the same destination folder (without subfolders)?

Obviously there is the problem of having duplicates in the source hierarchy. I wouldn't mind if they are overwritten.

Example: I need to copy every .txt file in the following hierarchy

```
/foo/a.txt
/foo/x.jpg
/foo/bar/a.txt
/foo/bar/c.jpg
/foo/bar/b.txt
```

To a folder named 'dest' and get:

```
/dest/a.txt
/dest/b.txt
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

In bash:

```
find /foo -iname '*.txt' -exec cp \{\} /dest/ \;
```

`find` will find all the files under the path `/foo` matching the wildcard `*.txt`, case insensitively (That's what `-iname` means). For each file, `find` will execute `cp {} /dest/`, with the found file in place of `{}`.

Comment: -exec cp -t dest/ {} +  will be faster, because it only has to run cp once, with multiple arguments.  -t is short for --target-directory.  -l may be useful here, to make hardlinks. instead.  And maybe -u, to end up with the newest version for each filename, instead of the first one find comes to.

Comment: General bash question here... is {} specific to find or is that a way to represent a piped in value?

Comment: @BrianBolton `{}` is specific to `find`

Comment: check out `man find` to see **more options** on which files `find` will find

Answer (score 14):

The only problem with Magnus' solution is that it forks off a new "cp" process for every file, which is not terribly efficient especially if there is a large number of files.

On Linux (or other systems with GNU coreutils) you can do:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 echo cp -t a
```

(The -0 allows it to work when your filenames have weird characters -- like spaces -- in them.)

Unfortunately I think Macs come with BSD-style tools. Anyone know a "standard" equivalent to the "-t" switch?

Comment: The only issue with this is that you can exceed the command line buffer using xargs if the number of files is very large.

Comment: Not true. From the OS X man page (but true on every Unix I've used): "Any arguments specified on the command line are given to utility upon each invocation, followed by _some number_ of the arguments read from the standard input of xargs.  The utility is _repeatedly executed_ until standard input is exhausted." (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: I believe I saw the behavior on cygwin some time ago where it did not do that. I then made the conclusion that was posix behavior (my fault for not actually checking the doc).

Comment: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xargs1.html Crtl-F "limitations" ... Apparently I was using the "-i" option when this happened.

Comment: I’m very confused by the `a` you’ve got at the end of the pipeline. Is that supposed to be there, and if so, is it a command for xargs or cp?

Comment: @StevenLu It's the destination directory -- I could have picked a better name in hindsight. Normally the destination directory is the last parameter for `cp`. The `-t` flag flips that so it's first, allowing xargs to put the file names at the end.

Comment: That makes sense and I'm not sure why I was even confused, I definitely knew the meaning of `-t` but forgot that it takes a destination path!

Answer (score 12):

The answers above don't allow for name collisions as the asker didn't mind files being over-written.

I do mind files being over-written so came up with a different approach. Replacing each / in the path with - keep the hierarchy in the names, and puts all the files in one flat folder.

We use find to get the list of all files, then awk to create a mv command with the original filename and the modified filename then pass those to bash to be executed.

```
find ./from -type f | awk '{ str=$0; sub(/\.\//, "", str); gsub(/\//, "-", str); print "mv " $0 " ./to/" str }' | bash
```

where ./from and ./to are directories to mv from and to.

Comment: This doesn't account for odd characters in file names, like spaces.

Comment: @NathanJ.Brauer You can fix this with judicious placing of \" in the mv command at the end. (I tried editing the answer to show this but got rejected. Thanks moderators.)

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to run just one command, why not cons one up and run it?  Like so:

```
$ find /foo  -name '*.txt' | xargs echo | sed -e 's/^/cp /' -e 's|$| /dest|' | bash -sx
```

But that won't matter too much performance-wise unless you do this a lot or have a ton of files.  Be careful of name collusions, however.  I noticed in testing that GNU cp at least warns of collisions:

```
cp: will not overwrite just-created `/dest/tubguide.tex' with `./texmf/tex/plain/tugboat/tubguide.tex'
```

I think the cleanest is:

```
$ find /foo  -name '*.txt' | xargs -i cp {} /dest
```

Less syntax to remember than the -exec option.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the man page for cp on a FreeBSD box goes, there's no need for a -t switch. cp will assume the last argument on the command line to be the target directory if more than two names are passed.

Comment: the point of -t is that it lets you put the target as one of the first args.  xargs doesn't make it easy to put args in the middle.