# How to detect all music on a harddrive, then copy it to a folder in PHP?

Tags: php

How to detect all music on a harddrive, then copy it to a folder in PHP?
I have 3 folder named music1, music2, music3 I want to get all the music from those folders and move it to a one folder named Music. Is this possible in php?

Comment: Just to clarify: all folders are on the same machine, right? So we're not taling about a client-server (browser-server) scenario.

Comment: select with glob() if your happy to determine a music file based on its extension, then rename() to move. or just use the os functions

Comment: on whose harddrive? (client or server?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function moveMyMusic($path){
    if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
            @rename($path . $file, '/mynewmusic/'.$file)
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
moveMyMusic('/music1/');
moveMyMusic('/music2/');
moveMyMusic('/music3/');
```

It doesn't look for music files only and will not overwrite existing files, but keep them in the original directory.

Quite frankly, there are easier ways to do that, like this one using bash: [Unix shell file copy flattening folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621/unix-shell-file-copy-flattening-folder-structure)

Comment: inside the loop you can check file extensions using fnmatch() to match music files

Comment: @Dagon it does but it will reach memory limit if you work with large files which music files usually are

Comment: @criticus: glob doesn't touch the file itself, it's just getting it's name (and maybe path), therefore the file size is not important for memory consumption. Bigger killer is the regexp which in that case is not necessary.

Comment: @criticus i don't see how file size is an issue, glob just gets the file names, all that is needed for moving them.

Comment: @freedy K. Dude Nice If I could give +100 I would, but deal with +1